# Sortable Table Row with Nested Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-sortable

In my rails app, a Timesheet has_many Entries and an Entry belongs_to a Timesheet.

```
class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries, order: 'position', dependent: :destroy
end


class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :timesheet
end
```

I'm following Railscast 147 for sortable lists (the updated version). In the development log I notice that my params hash correctly updates the sort order, but on reload it doesn't save the positions correctly. Furthermore, the request is being processed by the create action instead of my custom sort action. Here's my controller.

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user
  before_filter :find_timesheet

  def index
    @entries = @timesheet.entries.order("position")
    @entry = @timesheet.entries.build
  end

  def create
    @entry = @timesheet.entries.build(params[:entry])
    @entry.position = @timesheet.entries.count + 1
    if @entry.save
      #flash[:notice] = "Entry created"
      #redirect_to timesheet_entries_path
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to timesheet_entries_path }
        format.js
      end
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Entry could not be added"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @entry = @timesheet.entries.find(params[:id])
    @entry.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to timesheet_entries_path, flash[:notice] = "Entry destroyed" }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def sort
    params[:entry].each_with_index do |id, index|
      @timesheet.entries.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})
    end
    render nothing: true
  end

  private

    def find_timesheet
      @timesheet = Timesheet.find(params[:timesheet_id])
    end  
end
```

and my routes.rb file.

```
Sledsheet::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :timesheets do
    resources :entries, only: [:index, :create, :destroy] do
      collection { post :sort }
    end
  end
end
```

The entries.js.coffee

```
jQuery -> 
    $("#entries tbody").sortable(
        helper: fixHelper
        update: ->
            $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
    ).disableSelection()
```

The output from the development log

```
Started POST "/timesheets/8/entries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-04 20:14:18 -0400
Processing by EntriesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"entry"=>["60", "59", "61"], "timesheet_id"=>"8"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'qDs53hgOWfRMbNN9JKau3w' LIMIT 1
  Timesheet Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "timesheets".* FROM "timesheets" WHERE "timesheets"."id" = ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", "8"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for "60":String):
  app/controllers/entries_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

I googled the error about the undefined method, but I'm confused why the create action would be called in this case anyway? I do have a new_entry form on the page, that creates a new entry via Ajax. Perhaps this is interfering with the sort? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why there's no 'stringify_keys' method is *because* you're passing an array to the create action and not the sort action. 
What do you have for `data-update-url` in your erb.html file? 
Should be `sort_entries_path`.

Comment: the data-update-url is sort_timesheet_entries_url which I think is the correct url according to rake routes

Comment: I'm still not sure why it's going to the create action, but I'd bet you need to fetch `@timesheet` at some point in the sort action. So include the `timesheet_id` in the params and then use your `find_timesheet` method.